# How to avoid 'UNC paths are not supported' error when setting up VS Code for Motoko on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, unc, motoko

I'm on Windows 10 and trying to set up VS Code to work with Motoko. I installed WSL and the extensions to connect remotely on VS Code,  to do the hello-world sample project you can find here: https://internetcomputer.org/docs/current/samples/hello/
I am able to start the dfx server but when I go to dfx deploy I get this error:

```
Stderr:
'\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\louis\ic-projects\hello2\hello'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

On the command line I tried mapping the path to a Z drive but it said that the network name cannot be found.
So I'm trying to figure out how to run the project from a path that it will recognize. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve it, it looks like the problem was with node being installed on my Windows environment but not Linux and when I went to Ubuntu/mnt/c there was nothing in there in the way of files from my C drive for my app to access. So I installed node on Linux, then deleted the recent node_modules and ran `npm install` in the directory as per this thread [Build nodejs Fail with exit status 126 - Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416029/build-nodejs-fail-with-exit-status-126-permission-denied), and installed and upgraded `webpack-cli` and then the app started working, which I found here:
[How to solve [webpack-cli] TypeError: cli.isMultipleCompiler is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72637891/how-to-solve-webpack-cli-typeerror-cli-ismultiplecompiler-is-not-a-function)